# No route matches for signout path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am stuck in weird situation. i have seen many answers on SO forum, but nothing solved my issue. i am developing a ruby on rails application. I have created sign up and sign in successfully. but my sign out is not working.
 Here is my view for sign out in applications header

```
<div class="header">
    <%= image_tag "header.png", :class => "headerimg" %>
    <% unless current_user.blank? %>
    <div id="menu_container" >
        <ul class="sf-menu" id="nav" >
            <li style="margin-left:10%">
               <%= link_to current_user.First_Name, {} %>    
            </li>
            <li>
               <%= link_to "notif", {} %>
            </li>
            <li id="logout" style="margin-left:55%;">
               <%= link_to "Log out", signout_path, method: "delete"  %>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

my controller for session is

```
def destroy 
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_url
end
```

my sessions helper for sign out is

```
def sign_out        
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    self.current_user = nil
end
```

result of my rake routes is:

```
Helper     HTTP Verb       Path     Controller#Action
Path / Url          
users_path      GET     /users(.:format)    users#index
                POST    /users(.:format)    users#create
new_user_path   GET     /users/new(.:format)    users#new
edit_user_path  GET     /users/:id/edit(.:format)   users#edit
user_path       GET     /users/:id(.:format)    users#show
                PATCH   /users/:id(.:format)    users#update
                PUT     /users/:id(.:format)    users#update
                DELETE  /users/:id(.:format)    users#destroy
sessions_path   POST    /sessions(.:format)     sessions#create
new_session_path    GET     /sessions/new(.:format)     sessions#new
session_path    DELETE  /sessions/:id(.:format)     sessions#destroy
root_path   GET     /   static_pages#home
signup_path     GET     /signup(.:format)   users#new
signin_path     GET     /signin(.:format)   sessions#new
signout_path    DELETE  /signout(.:format)  sessions#destroy
default_path    GET     /default(.:format)  static_pages#default
```

i am unable to figure out what is wrong i am doing. i am followin Michael Hartl.
Plz point me to right direction.

Thanks

**EDIT**
here is the error that i am getting

```
No route matches [GET] "/signout"
```

here is the full trace of errors

```
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: You forgot including error backtrace.
EDIT Make sure your JavaScripts are working properly.

Comment: Make sure you have included `//= require jquery_ujs` in you application.js

Comment: @IshankGupta i have added the above line you highlighted in application.js file

Comment: @MarekLipka i have Framework Trace and Full trace on error page. Do i post that traces?? for EDIT part, i have added these lines `<%= javascript_include_tag "defaults", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>'

Comment: Please post the full traces.

Comment: check the edit in question for Full trace

Comment: Including error message itself, of course.

Comment: Again: JavaScripts. Something is wrong with them. Make sure you include them in layout.

Comment: do i have to use Bootstrap??

Comment: Its clear from the error that `[GET] "/signout"` its trying GET request for signout and not DELETE. Hence your problem lies in jquery.ujs file,check if its loading fine.

Comment: You don't need bootstrap to achieve your goal. Make sure you include JS in layout. If the answer is yes, check browser console for JS errors.

Comment: the issue is with js. I was not using '<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>'. by adding this to my application layouts page, it started working. Thaks alot guys for pointing me the direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `link_to` is written correctly, yet you can see it does a `GET` request. Since the method `DELETE` is enforced using javascript, most likely you are not including `application.js` or you have an error in your javascript, preventing it to be parsed correctly.

So make sure to have, in your application layout (`views/layouts/application.html.erb`)

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Or check errors in your browsers javascript console.